# Can a React usestate update be nested in another useState functional update?

Tags: reactjs, listener, use-effect, use-state, pure-function

There are `n` items the user can vote on.
There are two React states:

- `votes` is an array of the user's votes on every item.

  const [votes, setVotes] = useState({});
- `voteChanges` indicates how many times the user changed their votes on any of the items.

  const [voteChanges, setVoteChanges] = useState(0);

We have a database listener defined in a `useEffect`. When votes are added/changed in the database, the listener gets called. We need the state `votes` to compare every new vote with its previous value in `votes` to decide whether to increment `voteChanges`. However, we cannot define `votes` as a dependency in `useEffect`, otherwise we will end up in an infinite loop. To get access to the current value of `votes`, we use its functional update. Is it okay to call `setVoteChanges` inside the functional update of `setVotes`? If no, why, and how would you solve this problem?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    databaseListener((changes) => {
      setVotes((oldVotes) => {
        const oVotes = { ...oldVotes };
        for (let change of changes) {
          const itemId = change.id;
          const newVote = change.vote;
          if (oVotes[itemId] !== newVote) {
            setVoteChanges(oldCount => oldCount + 1);
          }
          oVotes[itemId] = newVote;
        }
        return oVotes;
      });
    });
  });
```

[This simple React App](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tracking-vote-changes-x3jhwj?file=/src/App.js) shows the complete code.

**Related Job offer:** We offer an interview spot to every developer who correctly solves this problem for a US-based full-time position. Check out the full description at: [https://www.upwork.com/jobs/~011fff0479dbd2b3e5](https://www.upwork.com/jobs/%7E011fff0479dbd2b3e5)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue you need to prevent re-call a databaseListener each render. You can do that by using an empty array as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  databaseListener(event => {
    ...
  })
}, [])
```

Please take a look at my quick example https://jsfiddle.net/h6tmeksr/1/

> Is it okay to call setVoteChanges inside the functional update of setVotes?

Yes, because React has a batch update mechanism ( version 17 )

Comment: Are you claiming that React 17 has allowed a React usestate update nested in another useState functional update? Based on what documentation do you claim this?